# SQL Puzzle - update an ordered list from a TVP

Tags: sql, visual-c++, sql-server-2012

I'm in desperate need of a clue on this one. I'm writing this in C++ CLI and using ADO for storage. I can place the logic in either the C++ side or in the SQL Server 2012 stored procedure I call. I have a table that represents a physical (ordered) stack of product. Not a big table, up to 20 items. I receive a partial list, up to 10 items in a message showing the re-ordering of the first 10 items.

First, I have to verify that the up-to 10 pieces in the message are already in my table. To do this, I upload a TVP with the items and their order to a stored procedure, and in the stored procedure, I do a count(*) on EXCLUDE. If the count is zero, I then have to reorder my table in such a manner that the up-to 10 in the TVP replace whatever order is in my up-to 20 table, and then maintain the order for any remaining pieces.

I'd like to say I had tried something and complain about errors, but I can't even get my head around a starting point. Sequences don't work because they can't include an order by clause. I can't do simple swaps because I have a table full of values and I don't know what (if anything) is being swapped. I don't have any working knowledge of cursor use in t-SQL, so I don't know where to start.

I've tried reading up on CTE, nothing obvious. Sequences, too limited. A cursor (below) works. Anyone have a better solution? Mind, the definition of these tables is mine to set, and although the Table (#TestTbl here) has check constraint to ensure Position is between 1 and 20, that can be removed and the Primary Key can be moved to equally unique foreign key IDA,IDB.

```
DROP TABLE #TestTbl;
GO

create table #TestTbl
(
    Position int not null,
    IDA int not null,
    IDB int not null,
    CONSTRAINT uc_FK UNIQUE (IDA, IDB),
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (Position)
);

INSERT INTO #TestTbl (Position, IDA, IDB)
VALUES (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 6, 6);
SELECT * FROM #TestTbl
ORDER BY Position;
GO

DROP TABLE #TestTvp;
GO
create table #TestTvp
(
    Position int NOT NULL,
    IDA int NOT NULL,
    IDB int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PKA PRIMARY KEY (Position)
);

INSERT INTO #TestTvp (Position, IDA, IDB)
VALUES (1, 2, 3), (3, 3, 4), (2, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6)
SELECT * FROM #TestTvp
ORDER BY Position;
GO

drop table #NewTbl;
go

DECLARE @ID1 int;
DECLARE @ID2 int;
DECLARE @LastCount int;

DECLARE MyCurse CURSOR FOR
SELECT IDA, IDB
FROM #TestTbl
EXCEPT
SELECT IDA, IDB
FROM #TestTvp;

SELECT Position, IDA, IDB 
INTO #NewTbl
FROM #TestTvp;

SET @LastCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

OPEN MyCurse;
SET @LastCount = @LastCount + 1;
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCurse
INTO @ID1, @ID2;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #NewTbl (Position, IDA, IDB)
    VALUES (@LastCount, @ID1, @ID2);

    SET @LastCount = @LastCount + 1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCurse
    INTO @ID1, @ID2;
END;

CLOSE MyCurse;

DEALLOCATE MyCurse;

SELECT * FROM #NewTbl
ORDER BY Position;
GO
```

Comment: Maybe provide a sample of what you have and what you'd like to get, a little data can go a long way.  Also, what indicates the order in the table?

Comment: Thanks. The data is just a Position (int) and compound ID (int, int). The compound ID is a FK and is unique. Both the stack and the TVP have this format. I'm more than happy to show whatever you need to see, but I don't really have anything. That is to say, maybe the TVP isn't the best way to do this? I'm desperate -- whatever you want to see, I'm happy to put up. You have something specific?

Comment: So say you've got a table with position 1-5 assigned to ID's 1-5, you've got new data that updates the position for some of those?

Comment: The re-order always includes all of the positions up to the first ten. So, if I had only 1-5 positions filled, the "current order" message will arrive with all 5 positions, and they may or may not be different from what I have, but if they are different, the five in the TVP would be the correct order. However, if there are more than 10 in the table, the TVP could contain any of those, but would only contain a maximum of the next 10 on the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried CTE + ROW_NUMBER approach:

```
declare @target table (
    ida int, idb int, position int)
insert @target values 
    (1, 1, 1), 
    (1, 2, 2),
    (1, 3, 3),
    (1, 4, 4),
    (2, 1, 5),
    (2, 2, 6)

declare @message table (
    ida int, idb int, position int)
insert @message values
    (2, 2, 1),
    (1, 2, 2)

;with result as (
    select 
        t.ida, t.idb, t.position, 
        row_number() over(order by p.prio asc, p.position asc) newPosition
    from @target t
    left join @message m on m.ida = t.ida and m.idb = t.idb
    cross apply (
        select 0 prio, m.position where m.position is not null union
        select 1 prio, t.position where m.position is null
    ) p
)
update result set position = newPosition

select * from @target order by position
```